# How to create horizontal funnel like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, svg

I wish there was a horizontal funnel plugin available in the market. I'm not a good js developer but I'm a designer with html/css skills in hand. I have designed similar funnel like below in psd but I couldn't find any plugin to plug in into the html. The funnel links should be dynamically adjusted too. Please suggest me how to build similar kind of funnel with steps title, conversion % on the second row in the funnel columns. I've also created this in css but css doesn't work because the funnel columns should be totally dynamic.

[image: Hotjar funnel image]

Comment: "*css doesn't work because the funnel columns should be totally dynamic*" CSS can be dynamic when controlled by Javascript. But of course, the best way to achieve this effect would be to use SVG or simple border-triangles.

Comment: I've built this using canvas, http://codepen.io/kijanmaharjan/pen/rLeVWV and we also have this http://codepen.io/agirton/pen/gyAzs using css but how do we show top two rows saying steps and sessions % ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how to draw your horizontal funnel chart for a given set of data using Canvas...**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var height=100;
var baseY=200;
var ascending=35;
var descending=35;
var barheight=50;
var data=[65,14,4,3,3];

filledLineChart(data,height,baseY,descending,ascending,barheight,'gold')

function filledLineChart(data,height,baseY,descending,ascending,barheight,fillcolor){
    var stepWidth=canvas.width/(data.length-1);
    var maxDataValue=0;
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(data[i]>maxDataValue){maxDataValue=data[i];}
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,baseY-height*data[0]/maxDataValue);
    for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(stepWidth*i,baseY-height*data[i]/maxDataValue);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(stepWidth*(data.length-1),baseY);
    ctx.lineTo(0,baseY);
    ctx.fillStyle=fillcolor;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
    ctx.strokeRect(0,baseY-height-ascending,canvas.width,height+descending+ascending);
    ctx.strokeRect(0,baseY-height,canvas.width,height+descending);
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        ctx.moveTo(i*stepWidth,baseY-height);
        ctx.lineTo(i*stepWidth,baseY);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle='whitesmoke';
    ctx.fillRect(0,baseY-height-ascending-barheight,canvas.width,barheight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

You can apply all your text like this:

```
// set a font and set a font color and draw some text
ctx.font='14px verdana';
ctx.fillStyle='black';     // or red or whatever
ctx.fillText('21.5%', 100, 175)  // 100,175 are the x,y text position
```

I leave it to you to apply your various text values for the chart using this simple text method.

Comment: Can we add clickable icons inside the top gray section? I

Comment: Use img elements for your icons and listen for their click events.